# MMDrawerController doesn't close if setNavigationBarHidden is true

Tags: ios, swift, mmdrawercontroller

I'm using MMDrawerController, which works fine everywhere except on the two views where I have `self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true`. On these views I can open the slider,  but I cannot close it, the button doesn't respond anymore. Here is my code in the slider:

```
let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ProfileViewController") as! ProfileViewController
viewController.currentUser = APP_DELEGATE.loggedInUser

let navigationController = self.mm_drawerController.centerViewController as! UINavigationController

navigationController.viewControllers = [viewController]

self.mm_drawerController.toggleDrawerSide(MMDrawerSide.Left, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and the one on profile page where the navigation bar is hidden:

```
@IBAction func menuTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    println("Profile: menu tapped")
    if let drawer = self.mm_drawerController
    {
        drawer.toggleDrawerSide(MMDrawerSide.Left, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

Any idea why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I fixed it by adding in appDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
let drawer = application.windows.first?.rootViewController as! MMDrawerController
drawer.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = MMCloseDrawerGestureMode.PanningCenterView | MMCloseDrawerGestureMode.TapCenterView
```